# What is the formal definition of a stacked based finite state machine?

Tags: automata-theory

The formal definition of a finite state machine is as follows:
A FSM is a quintuple:
($I$, $S$, $S$<sub>0</sub>, $T$, $F$)
$I$ - finite, non-empty input set
$S$ - finite, non-empty state set
$S$<sub>0</sub> - initial state
$T$ - transition function
$T$: $S$ X $I$ \rightarrow $S$
$F$ - finite, non-empty set of final states

Now I am attempting to modify the definition for a stacked based FSM. A stack based FSM keeps track of previous states entered. I need critique on the newly modified definition.

A stacked-based FSM can be defined by the following:
It is a septuple ($I$, $S$, $S$<sub>0</sub>, $H$, $M$, $T$, $F$)
$I$ - finite, non-empty input set
$S$ - finite, non-empty state set
$S$<sub>0</sub> - initial state
$H$ - finite state set
$M$ - modify stack function
$T$ - transition function
$F$ - finite, non-empty set of final states

$M$: $H$ X $S$ X $I$ \rightarrow $H$
$T$: $H$ X $I$ X $S$ \rightarrow $M$

Reasoning:
$M$ is the function that updates the stack set, $H$, by using the stack, the current state and the input to determine if the stack can be modified.
$T$ is the function that cause state transition, therefore, to transition between states it requires the stack, the input and the current state and will output a state that will be used in the $M$ function.

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are describing a pushdown automaton: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton